# Processing Sentinel-3 SLSTR data using python via snappy API

Tags: python, landsat, satellite, sentinel-snap, sentinel-3

I am trying to convert Sentinel-3 SLSTR S6 radiance data to a Geotiff file. However, I am finding converting the Sentinel-3 data which is in NCDF4 format to Geotiff format correctly very difficult. I am trying to use snappy API from Python. Since the lat-long information is provided in a separate file, my main problem is how to overlay geo-coordinates and radiance values from S6 and write it in a tiff file with the correct projection and resolution.

The code that I am trying before now is below.

Can somebody guide me in the process?

```
rad13 = p.getBand(‘S6_radiance_ao’)
w = rad13.getRasterWidth()
h = rad13.getRasterHeight()
rad13_data = np.zeros(w * h, np.float32) # numpy array of longitude
rad13.readPixels(0, 0, w, h, rad13_data)
lat = p.getBand(‘x_ao’)
long = p.getBand(‘y_ao’)
w1 = lat.getRasterWidth()
h1=long.getRasterHeight()
lat_data = np.zeros(w1 * h1, np.float32) # numpy array of latitude
lat.readPixels(0, 0, w, h, lat_data)
long_data = np.zeros(w1 * h1, np.float32)
long.readPixels(0, 0, w, h, long_data) # numpy array of longitude

###After I got the separate numpy arrays of lat-long and radiance values I have been trying to convert it into a geotiff file
xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax = [long_data.min(),lat_data.min(),long_data.max(),lat_data.max()
nrows,ncols = np.shape(rad13_data)
xres = (xmax-xmin)/float(ncols)
yres = (ymax-ymin)/float(nrows)
geotransform=(xmin,xres,0,ymax,0, -yres)
output_raster = gdal.GetDriverByName(‘GTiff’).Create(‘myraster.tif’,ncols, nrows, 1 ,gdal.GDT_Float32)
output_raster.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
####I am getting a 0 value here so not able to proceed
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(4326)
###getting a 0 value here
output_raster.SetProjection( srs.ExportToWkt())
output_raster.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(rad_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

When using Netcdf4 data for reprojection or assigning projection, using Pyresample library worked best for me. Especially kd_tree and geometry extension. You can also find a sample code snippet [here](https://gerasimosmichalitsianos.wordpress.com/2018/04/08/georeferencing-netcdf-data-with-gdal-pyresample/). They use lat long info from another file just as you are doing and then reproject the file using Pyresample.

Here is a function that helped me in testing the library and understand how it works.I am using another tile of a similar area although a different dataset (with the right projection) to then reproject my current tile (without correct projection). Might not be directly useful, however can get you going with a few changes as per your requirement.

```
def proj_assign(proj_data,swath_lons,swath_lats,proj_info,width,height):
    area_id = 'test'
    description = 'test area'
    proj_id = 'test'
    #proj_info = assign_proj(tile)
    projection = get_projection(proj_info)
    lons = np.arange(proj_info[0][0],proj_info[0][0]+proj_info[0][1]*width,proj_info[0][1])
    lats = np.arange(proj_info[0][3],proj_info[0][3]+proj_info[0][5]*height,proj_info[0][5])
    area_extent = (lons[0], lats[-1], lons[-1], lats[0])
    area_def = geometry.AreaDefinition(area_id, description, proj_id, projection, width, height, area_extent)
    swath_def = geometry.SwathDefinition(lons=swath_lons, lats=swath_lats)
    result = kd_tree.resample_nearest(swath_def, proj_data, area_def)
    return result, proj_info
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use high level libraries such as [EOReader](https://github.com/sertit/eoreader) to geocode directly your data:

```py
from eoreader.reader import Reader
from eoreader.bands import SWIR_2 # which is S6 band

# Open the Sentinel-3 product
s3_path = "S3B_SL_1_RBT____20191115T233722_20191115T234022_20191117T031722_0179_032_144_3420_LN2_O_NT_003.SEN3"

prod = Reader().open(s3_path)

# Load S6 band
s6 = prod.load(SWIR_2)[SWIR_2]
s6.plot()
```

[image]

More information on Sentinel-3 data are available in this [notebook](https://eoreader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/sentinel-3.html).

> Disclaimer: I am the maintainer of EOReader